# How to display choices in my form using django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that looks like this in my application:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    membership_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MEMBERSHIP_TYPES)
    membership_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Reading up on forms for my model i see that i can replace the models stuff with forms and place it in my forms.py. However when for membership type i don't know how it is used in the forms class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... You might want to read on [ModelForms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Answer (score 0):

Using the multiple choice field in the forms class.